# Firebase is not defined when outside of function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This code isn't in a function, it's at the beginning of my JS.

Here's the code:

```
var CoinFlip = {};
var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; //causing the issue.
var BalRef = app.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).child("userbalance");
```

If I remove this code, the rest works fine. I can't seem to figure out why it being out a function causes it to bring up this error. This is posted in all my HTML pages:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

Comment: As part of a function, the `firebase` variable doesn't have to exist until that function is invoked. When not part of one, it has to exist when your javascript is initially loaded. I suspect the problem is the order of your script tags. Can you tell us exactly where in your html the firebase tag and your js script tag are located, (eg. head, body, etc), and the order they are in?

Comment: @CRice They're placed in my body tag, I'll try moving it around.